# AJAX route always pointing from web root

Tags: php, laravel, axios

In my laravel project, I have a post route defined like this:

```
Route::post('myroute', function(){
    // Do things here
}
```

and in my app.js, I am using a library called axios and I am also passing the `myroute` as the argument of it's `axios.post()` method:

```
axios.post('myroute', { value: myargument }).then(function(response) {
    // Do thigs here
}
```

In my local machine, the axios call works fine. But in the remote machine, it doesn't. Because in the server, the application is not uploaded directly under the root. It's uploaded in: `http://example.com/level1/level2` directory.

So when the ajax call is performed on the server, it returns a 503 service unavailable response because it looks for `http://example.com/myroute`. But the application is not there at all. How do I tell it to look for the `myroute` route from the directory I am currently in (level2) and not from root?

I tried changing the path in `axios.post()` like this: `/../../myroute` but the ajax call is still pointing from the root. But works only if I hardcode the path like this: `/level1/level2/myroute`. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood then you need to use the java script to generate your URL sending. 
Use the **location.href** to get your current URL

```
var url = location.href+'/myroute';
```

Answer (score 0):

Might the relative path be the same in both environments? If you start the path with a /, it looks to the root. If you just do `foldername/asset.ext` it will be based on the working directory of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a configured instance of axios this way.

```
import axios from 'axios';

var instance = axios.create();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
   instance.defaults.baseURL = 'http://example.com/level1/level2'
}

export default instance
```

Now you use this instance instead of default axios.
It will use the subdirectory URL in production